# what should have been an empty string adds a value

Tags: python, string, object

well I'm doing a free code camp project and something quite strange is happening to me a function works perfectly with an object instance and fails with another one creating instead of an empty string a string with a value that I had used before but I don't know what could be the cause I leave below the whole code but where you should pay attention is in line 25 which is the one that causes the error the related functions are withdraw I leave the whole code because by executing so many functions I assumed that the error could come from another so I wanted to make sure that the info is complete.

```
def withdraw(self, amount, cause=False):
    if self.check_funds(amount):
        amount = amount * -1
        if cause:
            self.ledger.append('"amount" : ' + str(amount) + ' "description" : ' + str(cause))
            self.value += amount
            print(self.ledger)
            return True
        else:
            self.ledger.append('') # line 25
            return True
```

*******whole code below*******

```
class Category:
    def __init__(self, categorie):
        self.categorie = categorie
        self.value = 0
        self.ledger = []
        print ("el objeto "+ categorie + " ha sido creado")

    def deposit(self, amount, cause=False):
        if cause:
            self.ledger.append('"amount" : ' + str(amount) + ' "description" : ' + str(cause))
            self.value += amount
            print(self.ledger)
        else:
            self.ledger.append('')
        
    def withdraw(self, amount, cause=False):
        if self.check_funds(amount):
            amount = amount * -1
            if cause:
                self.ledger.append('"amount" : ' + str(amount) + ' "description" : ' + str(cause))
                self.value += amount
                print(self.ledger)
                return True
            else:
                self.ledger.append('')
                return True   
        else:
            return False


    def get_balance(self):
        return self.value

    def check_funds(self, amount):
        if amount > self.value:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def transfer(self, amount, category):
        if self.check_funds(amount):
            category.deposit(amount, "Transfer from " + self.categorie)
            self.withdraw(amount, "Transfer to " + category.categorie)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        asterisk = 15 - len(self.categorie) / 2
        devolver = (("*"*int(asterisk)) + self.categorie + ("*"*int(asterisk)) + "\n")
        for i in self.ledger:
            description = ""
            amount = ""
            description = i.find("description")
            description = description + len("description  : ")
            description_str = i[description:]
            for char in i:
                if char in "0123456789.-":
                    amount += char
                amount_str = amount
            if len(description_str) < 23: 
                devolver += description_str  
                devolver += " "*(30-len(description_str)-len(amount_str))
                devolver += amount_str+ "\n"
            else:
                devolver += description_str[0:23]
                devolver += " "*(30-23-len(amount_str))
                devolver += amount_str+ "\n"
        return devolver

def create_spend_chart(categories):
    pass

food = Category("Food")
food.deposit(1000, "initial deposit")
food.withdraw(10.15, "groceries")
food.withdraw(15.89, "restaurant and more food for dessert")
print(food.get_balance())
clothing = Category("Clothing")
food.transfer(50, clothing)
clothing.withdraw(25.55)
clothing.withdraw(100)
auto = Category("Auto")
auto.deposit(1000, "initial deposit")
auto.withdraw(15)

print(food)
print(clothing)

print(create_spend_chart([food, clothing, auto]))
```

Comment: WHich is line 25? What string is empty? What error are you getting?

Comment: `clothing.withdraw(25.55)` doesn't specify a cause, so it should go into the `else:` block that appends an empty string.

Comment: self.ledger.append('') # line 25 and yeah there is where the error happends dindt make a empty one puts one with whithe spaces anda a fifthy

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e8960029c561fb5daa353328b5900645
https://gyazo.com/737ef9ed8a8a248949b7b82540311dd4
that image show what appends

Comment: [link](shorturl.at/owQV6) there is the pythontutor that i use to test is in step 63 where the problem happends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `__str__()` method, not `withdraw()`.

When `i` is an empty string, the `for char in i:` loop doesn't execute, so it doesn't assign `amount_str`. As a result, `amount_str` will still contain the value from the previous iteration. So any ledger entry with no cause will show with the amount from the previous iteration.

There's no need for the `amount_str` variable, it's the same as `amount`, which you correctly initialize to an empty string at the beginning of each iteration.